# back and forward navigation with nganimate using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I am trying to create a simple application that has forward and backward navigation. The idea is- when going forward, the page must slide towards left while for backward navigation, it should slide right.
I am using the ng enter and ng view concept. However, when a user clicks on back button the page must slide right.

Following is the code for index.html page

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <!-- CSS (load bootstrap) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">


    <!-- JS (load angular, ui-router, and our custom js file) -->
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>

</head>

<!-- apply our angular app to our site -->
<body ng-app="routerApp" ng-controller="LoginModalCtrl">

    <div class="page {{slide}}" ui-view autoscroll="false"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the code for first state

#### language tips

SIGN IN

Code for second state/page - page-landing.html

```
<div class="container-fluid" id="landing_outerdiv">
    <div class="row" id="landing_innerdiv1" style="background-color:white">
        <div id="navdiv" class="col-xs-12 col-xs-offset-0 col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2" style="text-align:center;">
            <p ><a ng-click="back()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" style="float:left;"></span></a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Code for app.js

var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router','ngAnimate']);

routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/home");
$stateProvider

    // HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
    .state('home', {
        url: "/home",
        templateUrl: "page-login.html",
        controller: 'formController'
    })
    .state('landing', {
        url: "/landing",
        templateUrl: "page-landing.html",
        controller: function($scope, $http){    
        $http.get('json/data1.json').success (function(data){
            $scope.heading = data[0].heading;
            $scope.categories = data[0].categories;
      });

      }

    })
```

});

routerApp.controller('formController', function($scope,$state) {

```
// function to process the form
$scope.processForm = function(EmpId, Password) {
    alert('awesome!'+Password);
    $state.go('landing');
};
```

});

routerApp.run(function($rootScope, $window) {
        $rootScope.slide = 'slide-left';

```
});
```

And finally, style.css

```
.page.ng-leave  { z-index:9999; }
.page.ng-enter  { z-index:8888; }



.slide-left.ng-enter,  
.slide-left.ng-leave,  
.slide-right.ng-enter,  
.slide-right.ng-leave{  
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;    
    -ms-transition: 1.25s ease-in-out;  
    -webkit-transition: 1.25s ease-in-out;  
    transition:  1.25s ease-in-out;
}  
.slide-left.ng-enter {  
    z-index: 101;  
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);  
    transform: translateX(100%);  
}  
.slide-left.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {  
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);  
    transform: translateX(0);  
}  
.slide-left.ng-leave {  
    z-index: 100;  
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);  
    transform: translateX(0);  
}  
.slide-left.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {  
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);  
    transform: translateX(-100%);  
}  
.slide-right.ng-enter {  
    z-index: 100;  
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);  
    transform: translateX(-100%);  
}  
.slide-right.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {  
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);  
    transform: translateX(0);  
}  
.slide-right.ng-leave {  
    z-index: 101;  
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);  
    transform: translateX(0);  
}  
.slide-right.ng-leave.ng-leave-active {  
    -webkit-transform: translateX(100%);  
    transform: translateX(100%);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First RAW thing is coming to my mind is to add a class to the ui-view as you did. If we would have it the solution is simple, so we will style it in the CSS as you have.

I'm currently facing same problem, I'm creating a Cordova application where I'm using angular and this type of sliding is required.

In my opinion to determine the direction (back, forward) you could create a simple service wrapping $state.go(..) function. So you will have two functions **Service.goBack('state')**, **Service.goForward('state')**. This will help you to determine the direction. Then inside the Service you could try to change the class of container where you are generating view. Probably **$rootScope** will be the right direction.

There is probably one more solution, try to check onEnter, onExit function callbacks for states (of $stateProvider). Maybe it will help you also.